# Why is the marginal pdf of $x$ on the surface of a sphere uniformly distributed, intuitively speaking?

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

In [$f_X(x) \neq \frac{2 \pi \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{4\pi R^2}$? $X$ belongs to points uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788624/f-xx-neq-frac2-pi-sqrtr2-x24-pi-r2-x-belongs-to-points-uni#3788819) it was shown mathematically that the marginal distribution of the x-coordinate on points uniformly distributed on the surface of the sphere is also uniformly distributed.

This is just not intuitive to me from a graphical perspective. Could someone provide an explanation, preferably graphically, why this makes sense?

Comment: Well, the part of the surface area of the sphere located below the plane $z=z_0$ is $2\pi r(z_0-r)$ and the surface area of the whole sphere is $4\pi r^2$ so the ratio is $\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{z_0-r}{r} \right )$ which is the CDF of the uniform distribution on $[-r,r]$. The same happens regardless of which coordinate you consider.

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to get a much more intuitive answer than that. In particular, the analogous result along the length of the circle isn't true, because the angular variable is uniformly distributed but $\cos(X)$ with $X \sim U(0,\pi)$ is not uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Ian My followup was going to be the 2D situation along the circumference of the circle. From my derivation that was not uniform, as you stated. $\cos(X)$ in your notation is my $X$, the x-coordinate, variable right?

Comment: Yeah if you want you could call the angular variable $\Theta$ or something to avoid confusion. The point is that this is more specific than it might seem at first glance (my intuition would say that whatever the uniform measure on the sphere would do, the uniform measure on the circle would do "basically the same thing"), so getting nice geometric intuition out of it seems tricky to me.

Comment: @Ian I had the same intuition. I also initially had the intuition that the marginal pdf wouldn't be uniform for points distributed on the surface of a sphere. My intuition from thinking about it graphically is that if $X$ is further out from the center, there'd be a decrease in likelihood, so the PDF would be symmetric about the origin with a peak at the center and tapering off monotonically to the ends.

Comment: The key thing is that the area of a strip with $z$ between $z_0-\epsilon$ and $z_0+\epsilon$ is $2\pi r \epsilon$ so the probability to be in such a strip is $2\pi \epsilon/r$, independent of where it's actually located. Geometrically what is going on with that is that in order to deform the cylinder whose circumference is $2\pi\sqrt{r^2-z_0^2}$ and whose height is $2\epsilon$ into the corresponding strip on the sphere, you have to change its area significantly.

Comment: @Ian When you defined $z_0$ in your first comment, is $z_0 > r$? Otherwise the surface area becomes negative?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be $z_0-(-r)$ throughout (the difference between $z_0$ and the $z$ coordinate of the south pole).

Comment: @Ian Do you mean the area within the strip is $4 \pi r\epsilon$? I got
\begin{align}
    2\pi r(z_0 + \epsilon + r) - 2\pi R(z_0 - \epsilon + r) = 4\pi r \epsilon
\end{align}. 

And based on this the probability that a point is in that strip should then be $\frac{4\pi r \epsilon}{4\pi r^2} = \frac{\epsilon}{r}$?

Comment: The *probability* to be in the strip is $\epsilon/r$, but the strip had a vertical thickness of $2\epsilon$ so the corresponding *probability density* is $1/(2r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S^2\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ be the unit sphere, and let $C:=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\bigm|x^2+y^2=1, \>-1\leq z\leq1\bigr\}$ be the cylinder touching $S^2$ along the unit circle in the $(x,y)$-plane. It is a *standard fact* of three-dimensional geometry that the "horizontal-radial-projection"
$$\psi:\quad S^2\to C,\qquad\bigl(\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos\phi,\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin\phi, z\bigr)\mapsto(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,z)$$
is *area preserving*. In particular: For any $-1\leq a\leq b\leq 1$ the two planes $z=a$, $z=b$ create annular regions on $S^2$ and $C$ that have the *same area*.

Now on $C$ the function $Z: (x,y,z)\mapsto z$ is obviously uniformly distributed, i.e., $$f^{\rm cyl}_Z(\phi,z)={1\over4\pi}\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq2\pi,\>-1\leq z\leq1)\ .$$ Since $\psi$ is area preserving and keeps $z$ fixed it follows that the probability density of $Z$ on $S^2$ is equally given by
$$f^{\rm sph}_Z(\phi,z)={1\over4\pi}\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq2\pi,\>-1\leq z\leq1)\ .$$

Comment: I think OP is trying to intuitively understand how that sphere-to-cylinder map can preserve area (but like I said in the comments I think this is a quirk of 3D which is an obstacle to geometric intuition).