# Different approaches to finding the marginal distribution on surface of sphere with radius $R$ centered at origin.

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

I asked this question years ago [$f_X(x) \neq \frac{2 \pi \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{4\pi R^2}$? $X$ belongs to points uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788624/f-xx-neq-frac2-pi-sqrtr2-x24-pi-r2-x-belongs-to-points-uni#3788819), and I'm trying to use 2 other  approaches, but I'm not sure if they're the right approaches.

## First approach (from the joint PDF of $x, y, z$).

We know the joint PDF is the inverse of the surface area of the sphere, which is

$$
f_{XYZ}(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{4 \pi R^2}.
$$

So integrating this over $y$ and $z$ with proper lower and upper limits should get us the right answer for $f_X(x)$.

## Second approach

We know that the marginal pdf of $X$ is proportional to the circumference of the circle sliced from $X = x$, i.e,. a circle on the y-z plane with radius $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$, i.e.,

$$
f_X(x) = 2 \pi \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}
$$

Are these approaches correct?